# Are the methods of my MATLAB object exposed from the compiled .NET component with MATLAB Compiler NET?

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I have created a simple object oriented MATLAB class and defined some properties and public methods. When I compile the class into a .NET component using MATLAB Builder NE, I can only see the constructor and cannot access to any other method. It seems the Matlab compiler only compiles the first method (constructor in my case). I did not get any errors while creating the component. I am using Matlab r2015b.

Matlab class

```
classdef TestClass    
      properties (SetAccess = public, GetAccess = public) 
          v;
      end
      methods (Access = public) 
          function self  = TestClass()
              self.v = 10;
          end
          function pout = GetV(TestClass)
              pout=TestClass.v;
          end
          function TestClass = SetV(TestClass,inv) 
              TestClass.v = inv;
          end  
          function TestClass = Doit(TestClass,inv)
             TestClass.v = TestClass.v + inv;
          end
      end
```

C# code

```
TestClass TestClassObj = new TestClass();
NSArray value = TestClassObj.GetV();
```

Error I get is: TestClassObj.TestClass does not contain a definition for GetV.

Comment: Can you show the .NET code you're trying to access those properties with?

Comment: What about simply `.v` ? And do you get intellisense after the `.`?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen that will work in this case, but what if I wanna call the function Doit or any other function in the class? This is not working either.

Answer (score 0):

Calling MATLAB member methods from a .NET assembly is not supported by MATLAB Builder NE.

As of R2015b you will only be able to export MATLAB functions - the MATLAB functions can internally use classes of course.

Comment: Thnx for your reply. What solution would you suggest? Create a function for each method? Create a wrapper function that call every method? Create a demo script and compile it (not sure if this is possible)?

Comment: Yes you will only be able to call functions or scripts, the workarounds you suggested should work.. good luck

Comment: While @gregswiss is correct that you can compile functions and scripts, and that you can create wrapper functions for class methods and compile these, note that the components created by MATLAB Builder NE (actually in R2015b this functionality is in the new product MATLAB Compiler SDK) are _stateless_. So you'll be able to call your function, but it won't preserve any state between calls (e.g., the internal state of your objects).

Comment: @SamRoberts What would be your suggestion in this case? I understand I won't be able to modify the properties inside of the class I am generating the DLL, is that correct?